# Is my ToJSON Base64 instance sane? What would FromJSON instance look like?

Tags: json, haskell, base64, bytestring

I'm trying to encode a Base64 to JSON. I came across [this](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/187) dialogue. I noticed snoyberg has already included the `Base64` `newtype` in the FP Complete codebase, so I thought I would give that a try.

> import qualified Data.ByteString        as B
>
> import qualified Data.ByteString.Base64 as B64
>
> newtype Base64 = Base64 { toByteString :: B.ByteString }
>      deriving ( Eq, Ord, Show,IsString)

The `ToJSON` instance seemed simple enough. I'd appreciate a sanity check.

> instance ToJSON Base64 where
>      toJSON (Base64 bs) =
>        toJSON $ B.unpack $ B64.decodeLenient bs

The FromJSON instance is where I run into problems.

Studying other examples I surmise I must use `withArray` which wants a `(Array -> Parser a)`. This is where I get stuck.

> parseBase64 :: Array -> Parser
>
> parseBase64 (Array a) = ...

I've tried many approaches here, I'm confused as to what needs to happen here or even if I'm on the right track at all. If I could get some feedback as simple as "you're on the right track keep going", or being pointed in a different direction, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this exercise before: https://github.com/futurice/haskell-base64-bytestring-type/blob/0a1176d16c71c219fe113bc3f130f64d8dda47bc/src/Data/ByteString/Base64/Type.hs#L46-L51

```
-- | Get base64 encoded bytestring
getEncodedByteString64 :: ByteString64 -> ByteString
getEncodedByteString64 = Base64.encode . getByteString64

instance ToJSON ByteString64 where
    toJSON = toJSON . decodeLatin1 . getEncodedByteString64

instance FromJSON ByteString64 where
    parseJSON = withText "ByteString" $
        pure . ByteString64 . decodeLenient . encodeUtf8
```

---

After closer look, seems that you encode `ByteString` (any) as an array of 'Word8', (this what `BS.unpack` returns) for that you could do, and have an *encoded* bytestring in `Base64`:

```
instance ToJSON Base64 where
    toJSON = toJSON . B.unpack . B64.decodeLenient . toByteString

instance FromJSON Base64 where
    parseJSON = fmap (Base64 . B64.encode . B.pack) . parseJSON
```

This way you don't have to worry how `[Word8]` is encoded, as far as it's decoded accordinly.

If you like to handle array manually, then it would look like:

```
instance FromJSON Base64 where
    parseJSON (Array a) = do
        a' <- traverse parseJSON a  -- :: Parser (V.Vector Word8)
        return $ Base64 . B64.encode . B.pack . V.toList $ a'
    parseJSON _ = fail "Array expected"
```

or

```
instance FromJSON Base64 where
    parseJSON = withArray "Base64" $ \a -> do
        a' <- traverse parseJSON a  -- :: Parser (V.Vector Word8)
        return $ Base64 . B64.encode . B.pack . V.toList $ a'
```